# Certain principal bundle structure on $\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

I  ask [this  question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319147/certain-principle-bundle-structure-on-mathbbrn-setminus-0)  and  I  received no answer, so I repeat it here:

Is there a right action of $\mathbb{H}^{2}$  on some  $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{0\}$  such that this action gives us  a  non trivial principal fibre  bundle?

Here $\mathbb{H}^{2}$  is the Poincare upper plane  with its standard non abelian Lie group  structure

Comment: Any (smooth or topological) principal bundle admits a reduction to the maximal compact subgroup (see Steenrod, Topology of Fiber Bundles). The maximal compact subgroup of the nonabelian 2-dimensional simply connected group $H$ is trivial. So all $H$-bundles are trivial. Take homology groups to see there is no such bundle.

Comment: @BenMcKay  Thank you very much for your  interesting answer.

Comment: @BenMcKay  thanks again for the answer. This is a motivation to construct the following question: is there a free action of H^2 on R^n-{0}? A related question :Is there a right action of  a Lie group on a manifold  such that the quotient is a manifold(the action is well behaved) but the resulting structure is not a principal bundle?